# Setup IntelliJ IDEA Platform Plugin SDK on Mac

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to start implementing a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. For that reason I have to [setup IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/setting_up_environment.html#configuring-intellij-platform-sdk).

The official guide shows how it is done on Windows, but on Mac I don't have "installation folder of IntelliJ IDEA". It is simply an `.app` file among other applications.

**Q:** What path should I specify as the home directory for the Platform Plugin SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"installation folder of IntelliJ IDEA" on Mac is the application bundle directory (the `*.app` file). So, specify path to the installed IntelliJ IDEA `.app` directory as IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, the JDK usually resides at /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachies/jdkxxx.jdk. You could have more than one JDK of course and you could switch between them.

To inspect before going to the IDE, open you Finder, click "SHIFT-CMD-G" and navigate, or "cd" to it from a Terminal.

Comment: Thank you, but IntelliJ Platform SDK is not just JDK, it is JDK + set of IntelliJ specific libs that allow to access classes from `com.intellij.openapi` package.

Comment: Sorry! My bad :-)